# Small icons look strange in detail pane in Windows 11 explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

When I click on a 16x16 icon in Windows 11 file explorer and want to look at the details on the right side, I get a strange preview like this:

[image]

This does not happen with a 256x256 pixel image for example. But as the image gets smaller, the problem starts.

Here is how the icon should look:

[image].

At least this is not stretched shown in previous versions of Windows. How can I make the icons appear not stretched in the detail pane?

Comment: Is this a non-standard Icon?  I do not recognize it.

Comment: @John - No, on the contrary, it is a very standard icon. It's a 16x16 pixel PNG file.